# How to add a conditional Statement to a XML document?

Tags: xml

Is it possible to add a conditional statement to XML document ?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 4):

The question doesn't really make sense. An XML document is just a document. It may represent some sort of execution flow, but that's specific to the kind of XML document it is.

There's no "general" idea of a conditional bit of an XML document - and really no idea of a "statement" in XML either.

What are you really trying to do? What's the concrete problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry, concrete problems belong on BrickLayer.com

Answer (score 3):

As [Jon states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213512/how-to-add-a-conditional-statement-to-a-xml-document/1213532#1213532), XML has no general idea of conditions. However, if you are referring to XSLT, a format based upon XML that is used for translation of one text format to another, then you are looking for the [xsl:choose element](http://w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_choose.asp).

You use it like this (from [W3 Schools](http://w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_choose.asp)):

```
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="price &gt; 10">
      <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
      <xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer. Thanks @Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, adding/simulating condition statements into an XML is not advisable. XMl is really just meant to hold static data. Like parameters for various things. XML is not a programming language, and thus should not be treated as such. Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, I'm sure you can achieve what you want through whatever program will be reading and interpreting the data in the XML file.